# How to update password in all Windows File Share deliveries in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, passwords, subscription

I have around 20 Windows File Share subscriptions. Every time the password is changed - I have to manually update password for each of that file share subscription.

Is any easier way of doing that?

Like update it in one place and it will automatically update in all file share subscriptions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an easier way - yet. I can give you some of the pieces you need to make a way though.

The username and password data is stored as XML in the **ExtensionSettings** field **ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions** table.

Unfortunately, the username and password are stored as

```
<ParameterValues>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>PATH</Name>
    <Value>\\SERVER_NAME\files\TEST\Automation\Dropoff</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>FILENAME</Name>
    <Value>MEMBERS</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>FILEEXTN</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>USERNAME</Name>
    <Value>AABBEItDo8/msevjegsUsAlJf5eo1fTFjFe16FNk94Z+7hQvqsSHgW93DHqSL3rF2iHOCiwkvV9kEFGeUMG0tW4VV6gdQghXup+2V3BZHwo=</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>PASSWORD</Name>
    <Value>AABBpjdpbU2qN46RzMvYGfVPIW5B3cOlFtzXeIo8Sfn3uOSH5LiXbfptxYuFMNgR+5uYpHnh+6Y5oY4GDn6TXwOSYa5La+40</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>RENDER_FORMAT</Name>
    <Value>PDF</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>WRITEMODE</Name>
    <Value>Overwrite</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

I haven't found a way to figure out what the hashed values should be without changing one first and then looking at the Extension Settings to find the Password. You can update one manually and then view the new value to update the rest.

You will need a loop to go through the subscriptions that you want one at a time.

Here's some code to update the Password:

```
DECLARE @PASSWORD AS VARCHAR(150) = 'AABBpjdpbU2qN46RzMvYGfVPIW5B3cOlFtzXeIo8Sfn3uOSH5LiXbfptxYuFMNgR+5uYpHnh+6Y5oY4GDn6TXwOSYa5La+40'
DECLARE @EXTENSION_SETTINGS XML

--Add loop to go through all subscriptions
SELECT @EXTENSION_SETTINGS = ExtensionSettings 
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;

SET @EXTENSION_SETTINGS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="PASSWORD"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@PASSWORD")');

UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions
SET ExtensionSettings = CAST(@EXTENSION_SETTINGS AS VARCHAR(8000))
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID

--Next in Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that every time a new subscription is created the hashed value of user name and password are different for the previous subscription even though I use the same user name and password.  We have around 600 subscriptions created to write reports to a common file share using the same account to access it, however, each of these 600 subscriptions has a different hashed value for user name and password.
What is actually determining these hashed values?